# Compressing Large Dataset in Base64string

Tags: c#

I am allocated to fix an issue which is giving System Out Of memory exception. I am new to this project and I am trying to debug the code to find the exact cause of issue. This issue happens when data opens from oracle db and compress the dataset. Dataset contains more than 10 tables and in one table it contains more than 100 000 data, similar numbers in another tables as well in same dataset. Code is written as follows in Compression,

```
public DataSetObject(DataSet dataSet)
        {
            if (dataSet != null)
            {
                using (dataSet)
                {
                    foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
                    {
                        _totalRowCount += table.Rows.Count;
                    }

                    dataSet.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Xml;
                    _dataSetAsString = Compressor.ConvertToString(dataSet);
                }
            }
        }
```

where Compressor is a utility calss, and written code as below,

```
dsSurrogate = new DataSetSurrogate(dataSet); 
                formatter = new BinaryFormatter(); 
                formatter.TypeFormat = FormatterTypeStyle.XsdString; 

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    formatter.Serialize(ms, dsSurrogate); 
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    byteArray = ms.ToArray();
                }

                return Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

After this suddenly it throws exception as Cross-thread operation not valid . and in log file the eception is logged as below,

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectString(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.UnsafeDeserializeMethodResponse(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.DeserializeBinaryResponseMessage(Stream inputStream, IMethodCallMessage reqMsg, Boolean bStrictBinding)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.DeserializeMessage(IMethodCallMessage mcm, ITransportHeaders headers, Stream stream)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
```

Comment: I would suggest doing without the conversion to base64 string if you possibly can. base64 encoding adds approximately 1/3 to the length of the byte[] being encoded.

Comment: Just curious why you need this format. What is your actual goal?

Comment: There is no actual "Compressing" going on in your code that I can see, or did you forget to post it?

Comment: I would read memory stream in blocks so you don't get the memory exception.

Comment: Try this : http://tittylouis.blogspot.co.id/2011/02/compressing-and-decompressing-dataset.html

Comment: Base64 encoding will *increase* the length of your string, not "compress" it. Also, converting an entire table into a single string means that CLR must find a contiguous chunk of memory where to place this string, as opposed to many small strings for each row. If you are running on 32-bit, your entire process must fit in 2GB, and you will likely fail if you try to allocate any array or string larger than, say, 800MB (400M characters since `string` is UTF16).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize directly to base64 stream which can be serialized on the background either to MemoryStream or some temporary file if the former is not sufficient:

```
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            // or use temporary FileStream for this if running out of memory
            {
                CryptoStream base64Stream = new CryptoStream(ms, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                formatter.Serialize(base64Stream, dsSurrogate); 
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                return ms.ToArray();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that you are compressing any thing in your code.

Anyway, you could do a couple of things

1. Add [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=VS.110).aspx) in your app/web config
2. Make your project to run only on x64 CPU, you can change that from the Properties of your project

[This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps/) is a good read "The .NET Framework 4.5 includes new garbage collector enhancements for client and server apps".